# Is there a way to manage multiple devices from a single location

Tags: applications, desktop

If I were to install this in a computer lab, would I be able to control all the devices from a "teacher" device. Lock screens, send to certain websites, open apps, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you're describing, I think you're looking for classroom management software. I used to work for a school district and used LanSchool for this type of thing, but that was a Windows environment. I just did an Internet search and found Veyon is available for Linux.  That might be what you're looking for.

[http://veyon.io](https://veyon.io)